# Unable to deserialize a JSON array with Json.Net

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, json.net

I have a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "areas": [
      {
        "area": "New York",
        "isDay": true,
        "temp": "14"
      },
      {
        "area": "Washington DC",
        "isDay": true,
        "temp": "30"
      },
      {
        "area": "Los Angles",
        "isDay": false,
        "temp": "54"
      },
      {
        "area": "San Diego",
        "isDay": true,
        "temp": "59"
      }
    ],
    "status": true,
    "code": 200,
    "created_at": "2019/06/18 22:26:34.475",
    "request_time": "2019/06/18 22:25:28.306"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get the value of the the `area` value on the first/second/third object under the `Areas` array.
I've tried this code to get the value of the first area of the array, which in this case is "New York".

```
'Note that 'rawJSON' is a string variable that contains the JSON.
 Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawJSON)
 Dim naming As String = jResults("areas")("name")
```

However when I run this, I get and exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

I am trying to write a function that imports all 'areas' in each array with their identifier of `area` (such as New York/Washington DC) into a ListBox (so the ListBox will contain, in order: `New York`, `Washington DC`, `Los Angles`).

How can I do this?

Comment: psuedocode     jResults[0].("areas").[0].("name")    the most outer object is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. Your JSON begins and ends with square brackets, so that means it is an array, not a single object.  Since it is an array you need to use `JArray.Parse()` to parse it instead of `JObject.Parse()`.
2. Inside your array, there is a single object which contains a property `areas` along with a few other properties like `status` and `code`.  The value of the `areas` property is also an array, as denoted by square brackets.  So your code needs to account for both of those arrays by adding the indexes.  If you want the first item, that would be index zero.
3. There is no property called `name` anywhere in the JSON you posted.  Instead, the names of the cities are each in a property called `area`.

Putting it all together, if you want to get the name `New York` from this JSON, you would do it like this:

```
Dim jResults As JArray = JArray.Parse(rawJSON)
Dim name As String = jResults(0)("areas")(0)("area")
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAfEsx

If you're trying to get multiple names, then you would need a loop.  You could do something like this:

```
Dim names As New List(Of String)()
For Each area As JObject In jResults(0)("areas")
    Dim name As String = area("area")
    names.Add(name)
Next
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BtSa6O

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the JSON structure you have posted, the JSON starts with a square bracket. That's the start of an array, the `StartArray`: when the [JsonReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) starts reading the JSON, the first `TokenType` is a [JsonToken.StartArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) (what the error is telling you).
Then there's an Object, defined by the braces: `{ }`.
So you have an Array or List of Objects.

The first property of this object (`areas`) is of Type Array (or List).
It defines a collection of Objects.
Other properties, (`status`, `code`, etc.) have a single value.

```
[
  {
      "areas": [ { ... }, { ... } ]
      "other": "other value"
  }
]
```

You can parse the outer Array with [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm). The first element in the array (and the only one you're showing here), is the outer array. The first property of the first element in the outer array is the `areas` Array.
So you could write:

```
Dim areasArray = JArray.Parse(rawJson)(0)("areas")
Dim firstAreaValue = areasArray(0)("area").ToString()
```

The value of `firstAreaValue` is then `"New York"`.

This is can be tiresome and prone to errors. You can generate a class Model from the JSON and use this model to deserialize the JSON to .Net classes, making it easier to handle, use as Source of Data, modify, serialize back etc.

Your JSON is an Array of Objects, so let's build the Root Object as a .Net class:
Note that I've set the Type of the `CreatedAt` and `RequestTime` properties to DateTime (Date): the string format of the DateTime, `"2019/06/18 22:26:34.475"`, can be deserialized correctly.
`DateTimeOffset` is probably better. Your choice.

```
Public Class AreasRoot
    <JsonProperty("areas")>
    Public Property Areas As List(Of AreaObject)

    <JsonProperty("status")>
    Public Property Status As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("code")>
    Public Property Code As Long

    <JsonProperty("created_at")>
    Public Property CreatedAt As DateTime

    <JsonProperty("request_time")>
    Public Property RequestTime As DateTime
End Class
```

The Areas property is an Array or List of another type of object that contains 3 properties:

```
Public Class AreaObject
    <JsonProperty("area")>
    Public Property AreaArea As String

    <JsonProperty("isDay")>
    Public Property IsDay As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("temp")>
    Public Property Temp As Long
End Class
```

To deserialize using this Model, call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Type)(json)`.
The Type is, as mentioned, an Array or `List(Of RootObject)`:

```
Dim areasArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of AreasRoot))(rawJson).First()
```

Now `New York` is:

```
Dim firstArea = areasArray.Areas.First().Area
' Or
Dim firstArea = areasArray.Areas(0).Area
```

You can list all the Area names with:

```
For Each areaObj In areasArray.Areas
    Console.WriteLine(areaObj.Area)
Next
```